# ng-show not working with UnderscoreJS's _.isNull but works with val === null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I've got an element with an ng-show directive and when I use the UnderscoreJS helper function _.isNull it work the same was as using the standard === operator.

So this displays the content with newJobWorkPercentage is null.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-show="newJobWorkPercentage === null">
 ... some content
</div>
```

but this doesn't

```
<div class="form-group" ng-show="_.isNull(newJobWorkPercentage)">
 ... some content
</div>
```

I can just use the === in my app, I'm just intrigued why the helper doesn't work.

Comment: it doesn't work because `_` is not on the scope, globals will not be resolved. You could get it to work with `$scope._ = _;` or injecting it as a value, but that helper really is just `===` wrapped in a function

Comment: Yes I know it's just a wrapper around `===` but if I want to enforce a standard way of doing things I want it to be standard across everything, not one way in templates and another in controllers/services etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular expressions are only evaluated against the `$scope` of that view. So to use underscore  in your view you would need to add it to the `$scope` variable inside your controller:

```
$scope._ = _;
```

Now you will be able to use the underscore functions inside expressions.