# issue with condition in angular with if

Tags: angularjs

In my code the ng-if doesn't seems to verify the conditions. The 'hello' always displays before the table.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
    <h3>{{key}}</h3>    
    <div ng-if="_.isNumber('hello')">
        <h2>hello</h2>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
        <tr ng-repeat="(k,v) in value">
            <td><strong>{{k}}</strong></td>
            <td>{{v}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563549/ng-show-not-working-with-underscorejss-isnull-but-works-with-val-null

Comment: Thanks Simo but even if I don't use lodash  `<div ng-if="4 < 0 ">` I still get the same result.

Comment: I made a example on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/xatonupumo/edit?html,js,output and works the ng-if. Try to test your ng-if over this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use some function in the view, you need to bind it to the scope first.

I'm not sure if you can bind underscore but do try

```
$scope._ = _;
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-if needs the value true or false,

on your code: `<div ng-if="_.isNumber('hello')">`

It looks like your calling a function from your controller.